# Prove that there is no order relation "<" that satisfies the five order axioms?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have no idea where to start this question.

Comment: Often, the starting point for proving "no such things with properties ... exists" is assuming that it does and proving that it leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I hope you are familiar with the use of MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on this site.  A brief [introduction](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) links to the more detailed home-grown tutorial.  Just posting the image of an assignment with asservation "I have no idea.." may give your Readers the impression you have limited interest in solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Supposing that such an order exists, try to decide whether $i < 0$ or $i > 0$.